# Short code in python

Tags: python, optimization

How can I write this complete code in python in just one line or may be I must say something which uses least space or least no of characters?

```
t=int(input())
while t>0:
  n=int(input())
  s=sum(1/(2.0*i+1) for i in range(n))
  print "%.15f"%s
  t-=1
```

Comment: While restructuring this code, you must also consider other aspects rather than just trimming it to a single line.

Comment: Initially that sum line was also I did in 2 or 3 lines. Till now I just came up with this: t=int(input())
while t>0:
    n=int(input())
    print "%.15f"%(sum(1/(2.0*i+1) for i in range(n)))
    t-=1

Comment: @Lion what kind of ascepts you are trying to tell me to consider? Can you please elaborate as I didn't get it.

Comment: Why not post it on codegolf?  They're really good at doing this kind of stuff

Comment: This really is not a pythonic, hence recommended, thing to do. Python stresses readability of code and distilling a multi line for loop might look cool on one line, but is a bitch to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for _ in range(input()):print"%.15f"%sum(1/(2.0*i+1)for i in range(input()))
```

Answer (score 6):

You're welcome

```
for t in range(int(input()), 0, -1): print '%.15f' % sum(1/(2.0*i+1) for i in range(int(input())))
```

**EDIT** (explanation):

Firstly, instead of a while loop you can use a [for loop](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) in a [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). The last argument in the for loop is a -1 to subtract 1 every time instead of the default of plus 1 every time.

If there is only one statement in an if statement, or loop, you can keep the one statement in the same line without going to the next line.

Instead of creating the variable of n, you can simply plug it in since it's only being used once. Same goes for s.

Comment: a small explanation would also help if you could. Thanx. :)

Comment: `int(input())` is redundant in Python 2 since it would already return an integer (if one is typed in). Also, I think it should be `range(input(), 0, -1)` because the condition is `while t>0`, not `while t>=0`.

Comment: @Volatility You're right, i changed it to a 0. Don't you mean Python 3? In python 2 you do need int(raw_input())

Comment: I mean in Python 2 you don't need to typecast `input()` to an int. (Although `int(raw_input())` is probably the better way)

Comment: I'd suggest using sum(map(lambda x: 1/(2.0 * x +1), range(n)) as a replacement for the sum function

Answer (score 0):

`exec"print sum((-1.)**i/(i-~i)for i in range(input()));"*input()`

I know I am too late for answering this question.but above code gives same result.
It will get even more shorter. I am also finding ways to shorten it. #CodeGolf #Python2.4